# Particle formula for this

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, webcam, kinect

I wanted to build a particle effect with kinect like the one james alliban has done in this video with webcam : http://jamesalliban.wordpress.com/2008/08/28/playing-with-particles-using-a-webcam/ 
but I couldn't figure out the formulation of such a particle , and I haven't been able to find anything helpful in my searches, I'll be appreciated if anyone can share their experience with such a particle 
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of elastic particles on wonderfl
http://wonderfl.net/c/yeEo